# Java: how to make sense out of cryptic stack traces?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, stack-trace

While trying to run a unit test, I get the following stack trace.  I don't even know where to start looking (read my comment below).

Where should I start and what would you do to solve this?

*(note that the following stack trace is basically how I get it from Eclipse, without any formatting or anything: just countless lines of about 120 chars each)*  [I only pasted the five lines where apparently the problem happens]

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'acceptanceChain' defined in class path resource 

[.../chain/connector/...xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'xxxCommand' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is 

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxCommand' defined in class path resource 

[.../bl/chain/connector/....xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'yyyDTO#1d95da7' of type [yyyListDTO] while setting bean property 'yyyListDTO'; nested exception 

is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'yyyListDTO#1d95da7' defined in class path resource 

[zzz.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [boolean]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type 

[java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [boolean]: Failed to convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [boolean]; nested exception 

is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [boolean]: no matching editors or conversion 

strategy found
```

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: The first step is to format them properly so we can actually read it

Comment: Note that I arrived on a project where all the previous developers/maintainers are gone.  The documentation doesn't correspond to what has been delivered (for example the documentation talks about continuous integration but unit tests have been disabled), etc.  So I try to proceed logically, starting with unit tests, one by one.  And they're basically nearly all failing.  What do I do?  Change to another job?  The project is basically a huge mess (and it is in production).  I manage to fix bugs, but I cannot work with my usual "safety net" for unit tests aren't even **running** :(

Comment: @skaffman: which is why I mentionned *"this is how I see the stack trace under Eclipse"*...  Which is **precisely** part of the problem: Eclipse is showing them that way (which is an issue in itself which you may have a solution for) and I don't know how I'm supposed to format this properly.  I don't understand how it's nested, what goes to which "indent level", etc.  So my question stands: where do you start when you get such a stacktrace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the signifiant part of the message :

```
Error creating bean with name 'acceptanceChain' defined in class path resource
```

I guess the bean acceptanceChain can't be instanciated. Maybe because it has a boolean parameter in which one tries to inject a LinkedHashMap, as the following message states :

```
Failed to convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [boolean]
```